# How to call interface(instantiate) from JSNI in Google Web toolkit(GWT)

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have a class which implements interface, I need to call that method from JSNI in GWT.see the below code,

***interface:***

```
public interface HeaderFormatter {
   String format(String value);
}
```

***class:***

```
 public GWTGrouping implements HeaderFormatter {

    public String format(String value){
      return "<span><i class='fa fa-stop'></i></span>";
    }
    public void performGrouping(){
        if(isgroup){
          grouping();
        }  
    }

    public static native void grouping() /*-{
    //dont want to pass whole class to this method (this)
    //Need to access format(String value) Method which will return some logic
    //How to access that method here by passing interface not whole class
    }-*/;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public static native void grouping(HeaderFormatter hf) /*-{
   var value = // some String 
   var result = hf.@path.to.interface.HeaderFormatter::format(Ljava/lang/String)(value);
}-*/;
```